# If $f$ is a polynomial and $g(n+1)-g(n)=f(n)$, then $g$ is a polynomial.

Tags: functions, polynomials, commutative-algebra

> Assume that $f$ is a polynomial of degree $s$ which is not constant, and that for sufficiently large positive integers $n$, $g(n+1)-g(n)=f(n)$. Here $g$ is defined on the positive integers.  Must $g$ be a polynomial of degree $s+1$?

This is an ambiguous statement in Atiyah and MacDonald, page 119.

Comment: Not knowing anything about g, you can define it as you want to the left of n minimum (when the property $g(n+1)-g(n)=f(n)$ begins). Besides, knowing only the values $g(n)$, you can define $g(x)$ as you want between for n<x<n+1. Assuming g derivable, is there 
$\frac{\partial g^{k+1}(n)}{\partial x^{k+1}}=0?$ If yes, then integrating you get a polynomial? If yes, then do you get a polynomial by integration?

Comment: @Piquito This question has been answered by Winther.

Comment: Where, please. I interpreted "Must g be a polynomial of degree s+1?" as "Can be g a polynomial of degree s+1?¨(my english is weak so far).

Comment: To the OP: (1) I can't see the reason for you get rid of $f$ constant. (2) I suppose you mean that $g$ is (or better say, equals) a *polynomial function* from some $n$ on.

Comment: @user26857 I was thinking that the case $f$ constant should be avoided because $g$ could be some periodic transcendental function. But I think we can avoid this by realizing that there is not a unique representation of $g$ that fulfills this criterion; we can simply choose the polynomial representation.

Comment: I don't get your comment: if $f=c$ then $g(n)=n+d$, $d$ another constant, so it's a polynomial function.

Comment: @user26857 Nevermind what I said, you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes $g(n)$, over the integers, is a polynomial for large enough $n$. Since  $g(i+1)-g(i) = f(i)$ holds for $i\geq k$ then by telescoping

$$\sum_{i=k}^n [g(i+1)-g(i)] = g(n+1) - g(k)\tag{1}$$

On the other hand since $f(x) = \sum_{m=0}^s a_m x^m$ is a polynomial of degree $s$ then we also have

$$\sum_{i=k}^n[g(i+1)-g(i)] = \sum_{i=k}^n f(i) = \sum_{i=k}^n\sum_{m=0}^s a_m i^m$$

Changing the order of summation above and combining it with $(1)$  we get

$$g(n+1) - g(k) = \sum_{m=0}^sa_m \sum_{i=k}^n i^m = \sum_{m=0}^sa_m [S_m(n)-S_m(k-1)]$$

where $S_m(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n i^m$. The function $S_m(n)$ is the sum of the first $n$ $m$-powers [which is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula) to be a polynomial in $n$ of degree $m+1$. Since both $k$ and the $a_m$'s are fixed it follows that $g(n+1)$ is a polynomial of degree $s+1$ in $n$ for $n\geq k$ (with leading term $\frac{a_s}{s+1}n^{s+1}$). Finally if $g(n+1)$ is a polynomial in $n$ then by the binomial theorem so is $g(n)$.